# How can we categorize schools to achieve AI?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, artificial-intelligence

If we want to show schools at AI, which criteria are used?

For example I think something below, there are 2 school of AI.

1. Human level AI
2. Problem solution-level AI

At human level we aim to make machines think or act like humans. According to this we face two aspects of intelligence: i) acting like a human is called intelligent or ii) thinking like human is called intelligent.
At i, the researcher must know sociology to psychology ; at ii he/she must know neurology vs..

But at school 2, the researcher aims to solve hard problems in specific areas like industry, education etc. While solving, he/she can find different algorithms inspired from nature. He/she is not interested in human level intelligence at machine.

I used only one criteria to show schools. It is "human level intelligence"..

Is there any different idea?

Comment: If you build enough type 2 solutions, you might lump the best features into a general purpose problem solver, and call it type 1.

Comment: @aml and if you make a good enough type 1 solution, it would by definition be able to solve type 2 problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

We could classify AI in an infinite number of other ways; some based on outcome, others based on how it works on a technical level.  Here are some examples:

**Strong and Weak AI**

Your first 'School' of AI is probably [**Artificial general intelligence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) "(AGI) is the intelligence of a machine that could successfully perform any intellectual task that a human being can. It is a primary goal of some artificial intelligence research and a common topic in science fiction and future studies."  This is also known as **Strong AI**.

Your second 'school' of AI is known as a '[**Expert Systems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system)' which are defined as a system designed to emulate the decision making of a human expert in a specific domain.  For instance, Deep Blue, the famous chess 'AI' is an Expert System in the domain of Chess; it emulates the decisions of human Chess experts. this is also known as **Weak AI**, and **Narrow AI**.

In this system, we are defining AI based on whether or not it possesses human-like cognitive abilities.

**Communication Ability**

You could classify AI into groups of those that can pass the Turing Test and those that cannot.  One isn't necessarily better than the other; i.e. just because something does not communicate to humans doesn't mean it isn't intelligent.

**What 'Type' of 'Mind' it has**

You can classify AI into what I would describe as what ['type' of 'mind' it has:](https://www.rdmag.com/article/2016/11/understanding-4-types-ai)

- Type I  : Purely Reactive
- Type II : Limited Memory
- Type III: 'Theory of Mind'
- Type IV : Self-aware

**How they were made**

You could classify AI into those that were developed 'by man' and those that were developed using evolutionary algorithms and/or machine learning.  Deep blue, was programmed with a defined set of rules, whereas the Google AI 'DeepMind' that can win at 'Go' is much more of an evolutionary algorithm, and effectively taught itself to win.

Comment: +1 I retracted my close vote based on your clear answer.  I don't think *strong AI* is possible, but you described well some of the ways to classify AI.

Comment: If we believe that the human brain is totally physical in nature, and that we can simulate any physical system with a sufficiently good model,  then that leads to the conclusion that a general purpose AI must be possible.  not easy, but possible.

Comment: The problem is I don't accept the statement in the if clause.  The human mind cannot be reduced to the brain and machines do not understand. However, I do think AI is useful and it needs to get better.